# Putting a marker in google maps based on string location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have included a google map in my website.
I have the location of a person stored in a string. Is there a way to put a marker in google maps based on that location? If I had the location as coordinates it's easy, it's explained in google developers blog pretty straight forward.

Is there a way to extract coords from that location, or somehow search in google maps and place a marker on the returned location?

Comment: It's an address, not coordinates

Comment: What does the string look like?  Is it a postal address or a "place"?

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Using Address Instead Of Longitude And Latitude With Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925980/using-address-instead-of-longitude-and-latitude-with-google-maps-api)

Comment: still don't know why the downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Google's geocoding service to get coords from street addresses.

You can send a request to the API server, and it returns an XML structure containing a latlng coord, but you can also have JSON.

The [service is free](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), within limits.

Here's an example of an API call.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=PLACENAME

I've used this service before. You'd want to have the most specific details first, all separated by %20.
Eg. street%20town%20province%20country

**Update**

I did some reading, you don't need an API key. Here's [an explaination](http://opengeocode.org/tutorials/googlemap/googlemaps_1.php).

To get the results, I use jquery.

Here's an example-

```
$.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Scone%20%NSW%20Australia', function(data){
      console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location)
})
```

The result is an object, containing an array called results. Each array element is a result, containing your coords.

This example logs an object with the coords of Scone, NSW.

Comment: could you also add details on how to get the api key?

Comment: Are you joking? Google has those details. I even posted a link.

Comment: sorry, it's 1.30 past midnight here :D my brain just went through my brain. :D

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'll update my answer with an AJAX example too.

Comment: I was going to write my brain went through my head..... i think I will just go to bed

Comment: I was misinformed. You don't need an API key at all. Better answer above.