# Getting coordinates based on city name google map

Tags: google-maps, geocode

I am trying to create coordinates based on city with google maps, here is example what i have for now, i always get error?

```
var address = 'Zurich, Ch';

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({
  'address': address
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var Lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  } else {
    alert("Something got wrong " + status);
  }
});

var myOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng),
};
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous.  You need to use the returned data in the callback function when/where it is available.

related question: [Using Address Instead Of Longitude And Latitude With Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925980/using-address-instead-of-longitude-and-latitude-with-google-maps-api)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/braje7g3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var address = 'Zurich, Ch';

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var Lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng)
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    } else {
      alert("Something got wrong " + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```