# Google Geocode returns undefined when used in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, traveling-salesman

**Problem #1**

I'm developing a small Javascript application to get the addresses and Geocode it and save to database. I have almost 15000+ addresses which I want to get the lat/long of each. I'm iterating through loop, but the Geocoding function always returns undefined.

Here is what I have tried:

`InitDatabaseCities` function, which I uses to call:

```
function InitDatabaseCities()
{
        var cit = CSVstring_to_Array();

        for (var ase of cit)
        {
            var addrrs = ase.AREA + ',  ' + ase.CITY;
            var ltlg = GeoCoding(addrrs)
            SaveToDb(ase.AREA, ase.CITY, ase.DIST_CENTER, ltlg.split(',')[0], ltlg.split(',')[1]);
        }
    }
```

`GeoCoding` function:

```
function GeoCoding(addr) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addr }, function (results, status) {

            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                var latlong = latitude + ',' + longitude;
                console.log(latlong);
                return latlong;
            }
        });
    }
```

`SaveToDb` function:

```
function SaveToDb(area, city, dist_center, lat, lng)
{
        //var cities = CSVstring_to_Array();
        var url = "http://localhost:50264/api/service-areas/post";
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('area', area);
        data.append('city', city);
        data.append('dist_center', dist_center);
        data.append('lat', lat);
        data.append('lng', lng);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {

            }
        });
    }
```

`CSVToArray` function:

```
function CSVstring_to_Array(delimiter = ',') {
        var data = `AREA,CITY,DIST_CENTER
FOREST CITY,ALTAMONTE,0
WEATHERSFIELD,ALTAMONTE,1
RIVERSIDE ACRES,ALTAMONTE,2
ORIENTA GARDENS,ALTAMONTE,2
SANLANDO SPRINGS,ALTAMONTE,2
WEKIVA SPRINGS,ALTAMONTE,2
CLERMONT,WINDERMERE,15
`;
       // fetch("http://localhost:41847/media/cities.csv").then((r) => { r.text().then((d) => { data = d }) });
        /* This variable will collect all the titles
           from the data variable
           ["Name", "Roll Number"] */

        const titles = data.slice(0, data
            .indexOf('\n')).split(delimiter);

        /* This variable will store the values
           from the data
           [ 'Rohan,01', 'Aryan,02' ] */
        const titleValues = data.slice(data
            .indexOf('\n') + 1).split('\n');

        /* Map function will iterate over all
           values of title values array and
           append each object at the end of
           the array */
        const ansArray = titleValues.map(function (v) {

            /* Values variable will store individual
               title values        
               [ 'Rohan', '01' ] */
            const values = v.split(delimiter);

            /* storeKeyValue variable will store
               object containing each title
               with their respective values i.e
               { Name: 'Rohan', 'Roll Number': '01' } */
            const storeKeyValue = titles.reduce(
                function (obj, title, index) {
                    obj[title] = values[index];
                    return obj;
                }, {});

            return storeKeyValue;
        });

        return ansArray;
    };
```

When I call `GeoCoding()` in console with address, it works fine, but it doesn't work in loop.

**Problem #2**

I have a list of 15000+ addresses and I want to find the closest location from my current location. Like A,B,C,D,F,G are the list of addresses and I'm on Address Z, I want to know is there any better solution (instead of looping all one by one) that i can find which location is closest to Z address and what is the distance? Most likely a traveling salesman problem.

Comment: Please only ask one question in a question.  The geocoder is asynchronous, your `Geocoding` function won't work.  You can't return the result of the callback function that way, either use the result in the callback function or use a promise. Related question: [Getting coordinates based on city name google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877818/getting-coordinates-based-on-city-name-google-map)

Comment: Saving results to a database may be in violation of the Google Maps Platform terms of service. Read the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms

Comment: I'm saving lat/long of specific cities so on every call i could use the lat/long instead of geocoding every time.