# Is there any Web service that could provide the coordinate list of a specified street?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, leaflet, gis, mapbox

For example, there is a street looks like this (using Mapbox for map service).

[image: a street]

The street/road (marked as `R-205` in the image) is a complex curve line. Now I want to get the coordinate list (latlngList) of this road. However, I found Mapbox doesn't provide the coordinate list of this street. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Take a look at the google Maps Direction Service. You have to set a Start/End Point and that Service will return you a list of waypoints along that road.

Comment: If my prev reply is what your were searching for, I would post the code as an answer, but some feedback from your side is required.

Comment: @Dev0x Thanks, but that is not what I need. Because I don't know the start/end points,. Only the street name is known.  (The input is: Street Name, The output is: latitude/longitude coordinates of that street)

Comment: Ok, the geolocation API could be a first step in right direction then.  I´ve created an explanation for another question, guess that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600754/how-to-use-address-instead-of-lat-long-in-google-map-api/35601336#35601336 Maybe that service response will contain the information you require, but I´m not sure. If I have some time, I will try it.

Comment: FYI if you ever need a direction service, there's no need to turn to google since Mapbox has a perfectly good direction service of their own: https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/

Answer (score 0):

If you [look at that road in OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/228850865), you'll see it highlighted. Read [OSM's technical documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop) to use its APIs to fetch individual geographical features, or [download OSM data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) if you need road geometries for a larger area.