# Can you make a map based off address firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a program that creates a google map based off the address given by user input. As i can not manually embed a link for each page, how can i make it so that when a user answers a form with the address I can take that address and make a google map. Do i have to convert the address to latitude and longitude and then do that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15928376/8026947

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Google maps javascript API, you need the latitude (lat) and longitude (lng) to place a marker on map. To find the lat and lng of an adress, you need a geocoding service.

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map.

It exist a lot of geocoding services and Google Cloud Plateform provide one. First, you need to activate the Geocoding API in your acount (see [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) from the documentation).

## By using [geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview)

To find an adress (exemple: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA"), it's just a simple get request to the API with something like

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonaddress=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can get the lat/lng from the JSON response and use it to place your marker on the map. To do it, just follow the instruction from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) and you be able to place your marker by doing something like

```
let myLatLng = {lat:myLatitude, lng:myLongitude};
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map
});
```

## By using [`Geocoder()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder)

Like `@JeremyW` says, you can also call the geocoding service by using the `Geocoder` class from Google map javascript API (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15928376/11630806)).

```
let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

then...

```
let adress = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA";
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status){
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        if(status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){      
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
            });
         }
         else{
             console.log("No results found");
         }
    }
    else{
        console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
}
```